# Constrain a ListBox to only grow if the panel that it's in grows and not if more items are added into the list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

In xaml, I have this:

```
<!--The listing of the items-->
<ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding View}"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        Width="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListWidth}}"
        x:Name="lstBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding alabel}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

In the same DockPanel where the Listbox lives, I have another control that can vary in height (but not dynamically), let's call this control, B. So the listbox and B live in a user control, let's call that Master.

When Master is instantiated, B's height is set and then it no longer varies. In my Window, I can have several Masters, some which are taller than others. It is okay if the Listbox occupies the same height as B. It's not okay if B grows as items are added to it.

So, in essence how do I achieve the following:

- The listbox can grow only if it grows due to another control increasing in size
- The listbox cannot grow if I simply add more items to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was writing the question, the answer occurred to me.

The solution is:

1. Give control B a Name.
2. Give the listbox a MinHeight.
3. In the listbox, bind it's Height to be B's ActualHeight and it's mode as OneTimeOnly

As such:

```
<ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding View}"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        SelectionMode="Single"
        Width="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListWidth}}"
        Height="{Binding ElementName=controlB, Path=ActualHeight, Mode=OneTime}"
        x:Name="lstBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="{Binding thing}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This results in the ListBox having it's size once, and to that of control B; and then never growing again when items are added.